# Angular | get cookie value from callback response

Tags: angular, angularjs, cookies, session-cookies

There is an two domain.

Angular Application: samlapp.domain.com

Node Application: samlapi.domain.com

Node will call the callback which has the cookie and redirect to the samlapp application `(samlapp.domain.com/landing)`

**Issue:**

How Can I get the cookie value `SAMLResponse_0` from angular application.
Cookie set in the samlapi.domain.com but both hosted in same main domain.

**Code:**

```
  getCookie(name: string): string | null {
    console.log("All Cookies:", document.cookie);
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (let cookie of cookies) {
      const [cookieName, cookieValue] = cookie.split('=');
      console.log("Cookie Name:", cookieName.trim());
      if (cookieName.trim() === name) {
        console.log("Found Cookie:", cookieValue);
        return cookieValue;
      }
    }
    console.log("Cookie not found:", name);
    return ''; // Return null if cookie is not found
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please change your function as below and see if you are getting cookie name and its value:

```
getCookie(name: string): string | null {
    console.log("All Cookies:", document.cookie);
    const cookiesArr = document.cookie.split(';');
   for(var i=0; i < cookiesArr.length; i++) {
      const cookieName = cookiesArr[i].split('=');
      console.log("Cookie Name:", cookieName[0];
      if (cookieName.trim() === name) {
        console.log("Found Cookie:", cookieName[1]);
        return cookieName[1]);
      }
    }
    console.log("Cookie not found:", name);
    return ''; // Return null if cookie is not found
  }
```